# Why my object reference is not null?

Tags: javascript, reference

I can not explain the following behavior:

```
var persona = {nome:"Mario", indirizzo:{citta:"Venezia"}}
var riferimento = persona.indirizzo;
// riferimento ==> {citta: "Venezia"} <-- It is Ok

persona.indirizzo.citta = "Torino";
// riferimento ==> {citta: "Torino"} <-- It is Ok

persona.indirizzo = null;
// riferimento ==> {citta: "Torino"} <-- Why?

persona.indirizzo = undefined;
// riferimento ==> {citta: "Torino"} <-- Why?
```

I've tested this on C# and JavaScript and I have the same behavior.

Why my variable **riferimento** is not null or undefined?

Comment: Is that psuedo-code or C#? It's not valid JavaScript

Comment: `riferimento` is a reference to the object, **not** a reference to the `indirizzo` property. Therefore changing the value of `indirizzo` does not change the value of `riferimento`

Comment: There are few good enough answers, so I will not bother adding mine, just want to mention that that garbage collector will treat those two instances separately as you can see from your example, so holding such references to parts of objects (say when data is received by ajax) can end up with those unused references not collected using tons of the memory used in your browser. Explicitly NULL all of them in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's what a *reference* is.  It's not the actual object, it's simply a kind of "pointer" to the location in memory where the object lives.  Consider these two statements:

- You can have as many references to the same object as you want.
- When you set the value of a reference, you're only changing the *reference* and not the object itself.

So when you do this:

```
persona.indirizzo = null;
```

You're not modifying the *object* to which `indirizzo` pointed.  You're just pointing `indirizzo` to something else.  In this case, `null`.  The object still remains unchanged in memory.  And `riferimento` *still points* to that object.  (Side note: If nothing pointed to that object anymore then it would be out of scope and the system would "clean up" that memory as needed.  Different languages/environments/etc. handle that in different ways.)

It's subtle, but the difference is seen in these two statements:

```
persona.indirizzo.citta = "Torino";
persona.indirizzo = null;
```

The first line *follows* the reference and sets the *value* of something in the object to a new value.  The second line changes the reference *itself* to no longer point to the object at all.

Answer (score 0):

Both `persona.indirizzo` and `riferimento` hold a *reference* to the same object `{citta: "Venezia"}`.

If you use the reference to change a property of the object, this change will be visible through both variables:

```
persona.indirizzo.citta = "Torino";
```

However, if you delete one of the references, you do not impact the object itself at all, only one of the references to the object. The second reference still points to the same object:

```
persona.indirizzo = null;
```

If you delete both references, the object will no longer be accessible and will eventually be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

In C# (not sure for javascript) the following is happening:

```
var persona = {nome:"Mario", indirizzo:{citta:"Venezia"}}
```

Creates a **new object**, however persona.indirizzo is not the object itself but just a reference to it (actual object somewhere in stack).

```
var riferimento = persona.indirizzo;
```

this creates a **NEW** reference to the object that persona.indirizzo was pointing to.

Because of the clearing of the reference in the persona, the newly created reference is not changed.